# Android IMA SDK vast media loading reach a time out of 8 seconds

Tags: android, vast

I try with sample code and it work well but when i change it with this link: https://servedby.reviveservers.com/fc.php?script=apVideo:vast2&zoneid=7230&mp4=1. 
It throw error time out. Link stills work well with Video Js SDK.
Is this server fault? I try to research but can not found the way to extends time out.
Thanks

Comment: What's the difference between the sample code and your test tag? A timeout threshold of 8s should be plenty (if the server is up and there's a working internet connection ;-).

Comment: Sample code using test tag of google, i try the vast generate  from [link](https://www.adserverplugins.com/advanced-video-ads-plugin-for-revive-adserver/) . It is a plugin support gen vast tag. I test it ok on web but does not work in Android

Comment: MP4 and WebM should be okay, but a direct comparison to the sample that's working might still be useful. I did not check the reviveservers tag from a mobile device, but I assume the delivery looks the same as to my desktop client? Depending on how you test, SSL might cause issues and block the connection, triggering timeout.